# I am trying to install Android Studio in Windows 10 (32-bit) – studio.exe not opening at all

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded Android Studio for Windows 10 32-bit and extracted the zip file, but when I open studio.exe in bin folder, nothing at all happens. How can I run it?
While on notepad, I found this:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:



# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0xee53afed, pid=772,  tid=0x00002194
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_152-b02) (build 1.8.0_152-  release-1024-b02)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (25.152-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0xee53afed
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client  versions of Windows
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: Have you tried using OracleJDK?

Comment: I am using that only.